# Shuffle ordering of some rows in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, shuffle

I want to shuffle the ordering of only some rows in a numpy array. These rows will always be continuous (e.g. shuffling rows 23-80). The number of elements in each row can vary from 1 (such that the array is actually 1D) to 100.

Below is example code to demonstrate how I see the method `shuffle_rows()` could work. How would I design such a method to do this shuffling efficiently?

```
import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(20).reshape(4, 5)
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])

>>> shuffle_rows(a, [1, 3]) # including rows 1, 2 and 3 in the shuffling
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`np.random.shuffle`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html). This shuffles the rows themselves, not the elements within the rows.

From the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html):

> This function only shuffles the array along the first index of a multi-dimensional array

As an example:

```
import numpy as np


def shuffle_rows(arr,rows):
    np.random.shuffle(arr[rows[0]:rows[1]+1])

a = np.arange(20).reshape(4, 5)

print(a)
# array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
#        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
#        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
#        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])

shuffle_rows(a,[1,3])

print(a)
#array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
#       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
#       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
#       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9]])

shuffle_rows(a,[1,3])

print(a)
#array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
#       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
#       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
#       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])
```

Comment: If I try `print(shuffle_rows(a,[1,3]))` in Python 3 I get "None" in the output?

Comment: the shuffle is done in place. `print(a)` and you will see the shuffled rows

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Thanks for the clarification!